# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails , how to fix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Error : (`schoolapps_db`.`vehicles`, CONSTRAINT `vehicles_driverid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`driverId`) REFERENCES `drivers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Following code show the error:

```
public function addVehicle(Request $request){

    $vehicle = new vehicle ;
    $vehicle->vehicleCode = $request->vehicleCode ;
    $vehicle->type = $request->type ;
    $vehicle->routeId = $request->routeId ;
    $vehicle->driverId = $request->driverId ;
    $vehicle->status = $request->status ;

    if($vehicle->save()){
        return redirect('/vehicle') ;
    }else{
        return redirect('/vehicle')->with('Operation failed. Please try again.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but I think maybe you try to save the `vehicle` model with foreign key `driverId` that doesn't exist yet in your database. I suggest you to try check first if the `driverId` exist like this

```
if (Vehicle::where('driverId', '=', $request->driverId)->exists()) {
    \\your code here
} else {
    \\driverId not exist
}
```